# Tensorboard error: An op outside of the function building code is being passed a "Graph" tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

The following code replicates a Tensorboard error I keep getting. **Complete error:**

```
    TypeError: An op outside of the function building code is being passed a "Graph" tensor.
```

It is possible to have Graph tensors
leak out of the function building context by including a tf.init_scope in your function building code.
For example, the following function will fail:

```
  def has_init_scope():
    my_constant = tf.constant(1.)
    with tf.init_scope():
      added = my_constant * 2
```

The graph tensor has name: output_4/kernel:0

**With** the **tensorboard callback** I get the error, without it I don't. Bellow, the callback is commented out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Code:**

```
input_gt_boxes = keras.layers.Input(
        shape=[None, 4], name="input_gt_boxes", dtype=tf.float32)


output_ = keras.layers.Dense(1, name='output')(input_gt_boxes)

model_test_gt_layer_ = tf.keras.models.Model([input_gt_boxes],
                                            [output_],
                                            name="m")

model_test_gt_layer_.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(), loss='mse', \
                           experimental_run_tf_function=False,
                           #run_eagerly=True,
                           )
model_test_gt_layer_.summary()

log_dir = "logs/fit/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)

a = np.concatenate([np.expand_dims(np.arange(4).reshape(1,4),axis=0) for _ in range(100)], axis=0)
o= np.concatenate([np.zeros(100).reshape(100,1) for _ in range(1)], axis=0)

model_test_gt_layer_.fit(a, o, \
                        epochs=5, \
                        callbacks=[
                        #tensorboard_callback, 
                                  ], \
                        verbose=1,\
                        use_multiprocessing= False,)
```

Comment: I simplified the code generating the error even more, and posted the update. The model is very simple, I am not sure why this error is being generated. I upgraded my tensorboard from 2.2.2 to the latest version 2.11.0 as well. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

The eager execution had to be enabled: `tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()` and also set `run_eagerly=True` in the .compile statement.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()

print("Eagerly: ", tf.executing_eagerly())
input_gt_boxes = keras.layers.Input(
        shape=[None, 4], name="input_gt_boxes", dtype=tf.float32)


output_ = keras.layers.Dense(1, name='output')(input_gt_boxes)

model_test_gt_layer_ = tf.keras.models.Model([input_gt_boxes],
                                            [output_],
                                            name="m")

model_test_gt_layer_.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(), loss='mse', \
                           experimental_run_tf_function=False,
                           run_eagerly=True,
                           )
model_test_gt_layer_.summary()

log_dir = "logs/fit/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)

a = np.concatenate([np.expand_dims(np.arange(4).reshape(1,4),axis=0) for _ in range(100)], axis=0)
o= np.concatenate([np.zeros(100).reshape(100,1) for _ in range(1)], axis=0)

model_test_gt_layer_.fit(a, o, \
                        epochs=5, \
                        callbacks=[
                        tensorboard_callback, 
                                  ], \
                        verbose=1,\
                        use_multiprocessing= False,)
```

Comment: However, one cannot see the [graph](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/1961) while in ```run_eagerly=True```.